# Adobe Livecycle activity check text in document

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I'm using a process in Adobe Livecycle ES3. I have a PDF document in input, I have to check if the document cointains text. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PDF Generator installed you can convert the PDF document into a text document. This will allow you to check the contents as plain text.

Check the following link for converting PDF to text. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/WorkbenchHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb1df6c8912826bea3c5-8000.html#WS92d06802c76abadb-1cc35bda128261a20dd-6e77

You can then use executeScript or setValue activities or a custom java component to perform your checks on the text.

Another option is to use iText library in a Java Component to perform these operations. Note that this is not recommended with LiveCycle.